# how to update record file in c++?

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```cpp
void person :: edit_teacher(char *Id)
{
    int count = 0;
    fstream file; // as fstream pointer is on the last position so we have to mmove the pointer on the first poistion //
    
    file.open("TeachersRecord.txt", ios::in| ios::out| ios::ate);
    
    file.seekg(0); // it will move the pointer on the first location //
    if(!file)
    {
        cout << "File is not exist." <<endl;
    }
    else{
        
        file.read((char*)this, sizeof(*this));
        
        while(!file.eof()){
            if(!strcmp(Id,this->id)){
                
                cout << "\n\t\t\t*********Enter new record********" << endl << endl;
                setData();
                
                file.seekp((int)file.tellp()-sizeof(*this));
                
                file.write((char *)this, sizeof(*this));
            }
            file.read((char*)this, sizeof(*this));
        }
        if(count == 0)
        {
            cout << endl <<"Record is not found.";
            
        }
        else{
            cout << "\nRecord is Successfully Updated.";
        }
        file.close();
    }
}
```

The update file only edits the first two data types, others show as empty, and the last two give address?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You should write all your changes and the old content to a new file, rather than trying to modify an existing file.

Comment: Also, see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't manipulate the input file while you are reading from it.  Write your changes to a new file first, and then replace the original file with the new file only if everything is successful.

Also, you are reading each record in the file into `this`, which is just bad design, and will potentially corrupt `this`.  More importantly, you did not show the declaration of `person`, but based on your description, it sounds like `person` contains data members that simply can't be read/written as-is and will need additional *serialization*.  For instance, `char*`/`std::string` strings (flat `char[]` arrays are OK).

Also, you are not incrementing `count` if the requested `Id` is found, but you are checking if `count` has been incremented when the loop is finished.

Also, your code lacks adequate error handling.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#inlcude <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
...

bool readPerson(std::istream &in, person &p)
{
    // do whatever is needed to de-serialize a person record *properly*...
    return in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p), sizeof(p));
}

bool writePerson(std::ostream &out, const person &p)
{
    // do whatever is needed to serialize a person record *properly*...
    return out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p), sizeof(p));
}

void person::edit_teacher(char *Id)
{
    std::ifstream infile("TeachersRecord.txt");
    if (!infile)
    {
        std::cout << "Can't open File to read." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::ofstream outfile("TeachersRecord_new.txt");
        if (!outfile)
        {
            std::cout << "Can't create File to write." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            bool found = false;
            person p;

            while (readPerson(infile, p))
            {
                if ((!found) && (strcmp(Id, p.id) == 0))
                {
                    found = true;
                
                    std::cout << "\n\t\t\t*********Enter new record********" << std::endl << std::endl;

                    p.setData();
                    *this = p;
                }
                
                if (!writePerson(outfile, p))
                {
                    outfile.close();
                    std::remove("TeachersRecord_new.txt");
                    std::cout << "Can't write to File." << std::endl;
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (!infile.eof())
            {
                std::cout << "Can't read from File." << std::endl;
                return;
            }

            infile.close();
            outfile.close();

            if (!found)
            {
                std::remove("TeachersRecord_new.txt");
                std::cout << "Record is not found." << std::endl;
            }
            else if (std::rename("TeachersRecord.txt", "TeachersRecord_bak.txt") != 0)
            {
                std::remove("TeachersRecord_new.txt");
                std::cout << "Can't Backup File." << std::endl;
            }
            else if (std::rename("TeachersRecord_new.txt", "TeachersRecord.txt") != 0)
            {
                std::rename("TeachersRecord_bak.txt", "TeachersRecord.txt");
                std::remove("TeachersRecord_new.txt");
                std::cout << "Can't replace File." << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::remove("TeachersRecord_bak.txt");
                std::cout << "Record is Successfully Updated." << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```